# data-rel="back" without button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile site using `jquerymobile`

I want to make the back button to do what makes `<a data-rel="back">content</a>`
But I want to write this code,because I have check  condition before returning to the previous page

how i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to remove the `data-rel` , apply your own class, or ID and use `window.history.back()` within your own click handler.

I'm not intimately familiar with all the event handlers, or history handling in jQuery Mobile. But this is what I would try

Answer (score -1):

I would change the HTML to:

```
<a class="backlink">content</a>
```

And use the JS:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.backlink", function () {
   // create a back button and click it
   // ('<a>').attr('data-rel', 'back').click();
   // if that doesn't work (see comments), just call
   window.history.back();
});
```